# Choosing a Wiki for an academic institute

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

I need to choose a Wiki. Please someone help. Following are my requirements:

1) Need good control to the access variables

2) LDAP integration support

3) User Group Support

4) Good Themes and Templates

Mediawiki has the problem that it does not support Users Groups that intutively. Twiki and Foswiki have a problem that any authenticated user that has write permissions for a topic also have the write to change the particualar permissions for the topic.

Else, can someone suggest me where to look for the answer. I know about the WikiMatrix

Comment: Do you have any platform or license requirements?  Do you needed it to be open source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Foswiki](http://foswiki.org) is also very good - and free & open, too! It's specifically made for use on corporate intranets (yes, with LDAP!), with strong focus on ease of use, great WYSIWYG editor, fine-grained access restrictions, and per-page attachments. There are 250+ extensions and a very active community to provide support and keep it all up to date.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the answers you give to my questions above, Confluence is probably a good solution for you.  It is a commercial wiki product but very polished and meets all your four requirements.  It's also really user friendly.

Comment: I work at a university that uses Confluence...

Comment: Would be nice to have a link on the answer if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it fits your needs strictly, but I used to use this one and i was very happy: [Wikka Wikki](http://wikkawiki.org/HomePage). But you have to check if it provide all the fnctionality you need!

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by group support. If you really need to keep information private between groups, then MediaWiki can work, either by:

- **having separate instances** a so-called *wiki farm* which share the same software (so one place to configure all) but have different content - like the different languages at Wikipedia.
- as you say, using **[Lockdown](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lockdown)**.

And it's free, which is probably more appealing to an academic institute. Furthermore, it is:

- highly configurable (many extensions)
- template - tons of them (e.g. [Keypress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Key_press)) and you can easily create your own
- well tested (since it is used by so many people world wide)
- recognisable (thanks to Wikipedia) which lowers the start threshold and
- living - it is continuously being further developed.

If you want a more specific answer, please specify what you mean by group support.

Answer (score 0):

I am an admin of **Tiki Wiki CMS Groupware**, a full-featured, open source, multilingual, all-in-one Wiki+CMS+Groupware written in PHP.

Please note that Tiki is not just a wiki. There are a lot of other features:
http://doc.tiki.org/Features

To your requirements:

1) Need good control to the access variables
If you mean that you can have different permissions on who can edit the page and who can change the permissions of the page: yes.
doc.tiki.org/Permissions

2) LDAP integration support
doc.tiki.org/LDAP

3) User Group Support
doc.tiki.org/Groups

4) Good Themes and Templates
themes.tiki.org

Best regards,

M ;-)

Marc Laporte

P.S. Read more about **Software made the wiki way** at tiki.org/Model